# (js) if statement for key-press in game-update function

Tags: javascript

(Game) When the players object is reaching to top, the objects y-movement should stop moving to avoid passing the top.

I made an if-statement for that and it's working.

```
if(playerObject.yCoordinate <= 0){

    function_To_Stop_Y_movment();

}
```

However, the player wont be able to move down, and therefore stuck vertically.

What I need is to add a additional logic in the if-statement where it checks if the `keyCode 38` is pressed.

```
if (playerObject.yCoordinate <= 0 && /* keyCode 38 is pressed */) {
```

So the if-statement will only be true while the player is pressing the up-arrow.

This if-statement is within an update function which is running every 0.02 sec `(setInterval(updateGame, 20);`.

**EDIT:**

This is how I added keyListener:

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
 function keyDownHandler(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 38 ) {
```

But I don't know how to add that key-press check into that update-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a separate variable and set it to "true" when the up arrow is pressed. Then use that variable in your if statement. If you do it this way, you'll have to set it back to false at some point.

```
var keyup = false;
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 ) { 
        keyup == true;
    }
}

if (playerObject.yCoordinate <= 0 && keyup) {
    // do your stuff then...
    keyup == false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a position check in the keydown function. If the position is at the top, then don't execute the move function. If it's anywhere else then continue. Basically this:

```
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 ) { 
        if (playerObject.yCoordinate <=0) return;
        moveCharacter();
    }
}
```

This will check the position and if at the top it will do nothing. If it's anywhere else it will move the character.